# jQuery ajax - outputting files from an ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery, httpresponse

is it possible to output a file as a response from a ajax call? 
i've wrote a function for outputting zip files using an ajax call, this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ziplink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var spinner = $(this).parent().children(".spinnerbox");
            spinner.show();
            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"application/x-zip-compressed",
                success:function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    spinner.hide();

                },
                error:function () {
                    console.log('ko');
                    spinner.hide();
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

now, from the firebug console everything is ook, but i dont have file output. what is missing?

Although this is fully functional in the non-ajax way (a simple link to the action), i'd like to have the spinner animation while server process the request.

thanx - LuKe

Comment: I think you are not using content of file {data}

Comment: Your success function doesn't put the data anywhere. Where do you expect to get file output?

Comment: i expect to have the same behaviour of the non ajax way: being able to download file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".ziplink").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    $('.spinner').show();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'HEAD',
        url : _self.attr('href'),
        complete : function(){

            $('.spinner').hide();
            var _tmp = $('<iframe />')
                .attr('src', _self.attr('href'))
                .hide()
                .appendTo(_self)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    _tmp.remove();
                },5000);

        }

    });

});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4sMsr/3/

Comment: it works, thanks. However, this way has a side effect: to double the time for the responce, since we have two requests: http://i.imgur.com/hNnAR.png

Comment: yeah, hope you notice I send a HEAD request rather than GET so that it downloads only headers. You can further handle the request like checking 200 status inside the complete callback before letting user download the file.

Comment: ...how? i mean i just want to have a single GET request to avoid sending the request twice. is it possible? tnx

Comment: I don't think that is possible.. Im not sure